# Attempted to index nil with 'Name'

Tags: indexing, lua, null, output, roblox

```lua
local serverStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)


    local dataFolder Instance.new("Folder")
    dataFolder.Name = player.Name
    dataFolder.Parent = serverStorage.RemoteData
    
    local debounce = Instance.new("BoolValue")
    debounce.Name = "Debounce"
    debounce.Parent = dataFolder

end)
```

Comment: You have a typo. You forgot to put an equal sign when creating the `dataFolder` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot your `=`, you're trying to index `dataFolder Instance` with `new` instead of just `Instance` with `new`.

```lua
local serverStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)


    local dataFolder = Instance.new("Folder")
    dataFolder.Name = player.Name
    dataFolder.Parent = serverStorage.RemoteData
    
    local debounce = Instance.new("BoolValue")
    debounce.Name = "Debounce"
    debounce.Parent = dataFolder

end)
```

Comment: No, that's not why it doesn't work. Identifiers can only hold alphanumeric characters + underscores, they can't hold spaces. The real reason it doesn't work is that Lua's 
automatic statement ending works excellently without any semicolons needed in the middle of the line. There are actually 2 statements in that line: `local datafolder` (has the value `nil` by default) and `Instance.new("Folder")` (return value is ignored). The error happens on the line with `dataFolder.Name`, which gives the error message.